# How to re-download Lion to create a VMWare Fusion 4 virtual machine?

Tags: macos, vmware

I have a MacBook with Lion installed.

I bought VMWare Fusion 4 because I want to create a Lion VM.

As far as I can tell I need to point VMWare to the Lion installer that is downloaded from the App Store, but that file deleted itself after Lion was installed.

How do I re-download the Lion installer (and keep it around) to create a VMWare Fusion 4 virtual machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do to re-download the Lion installer is to HOLD down the OPTION/ALT key whilst opening the App Store and keep holding it all the way through to the purchased tab, from here you should see the option to install. Just download that.

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  I did what you said.  After download, the 3.75G disk image mounted, but since I didn't want to actually do the installation (I want to create VM in VMFusion) I ejected the mounted image and the downloaded installer deleted itself. :(  Do I just copy the mounted drive before ejecting or something?

Comment: Copy the downloaded installer onto a USB stick