# How to install OS X 10.7 and 10.8 in VMWare Fusion, on a 10.9 host?

Tags: macos, vmware, virtualization

I'm working on fairly new Mac Mini, running OS X 10.9.4 and VMWare Fusion Pro 6.0.4.

For software testing purposes, I want to install both a OS X 10.7 Lion and OS X 10.8 Mountain Lion inside a virtual machine. I have access to the developer downloads under http://developer.apple.com/downloads.

I can find numerous packages saying, for example "OS X Lion 10.7.2 Build XXXXX", but all of them seem to updates and are relatively small in size (~ 700 MB). I can't seem to find any image that would allow me to install a fresh 10.7 or 10.8 inside a new VM.

So how exactly do I go about creating those two virtual machines on my OS X 10.9 host?

Comment: See http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/25841/how-to-re-download-lion-to-create-a-vmware-fusion-4-virtual-machine?rq=1, http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/59790/how-can-i-install-mountain-lion-in-a-vmware-fusion-vm?rq=1 and http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/132142/how-can-i-get-a-osx-mountain-lion-installer-for-deployment-testing?rq=1. If the answers listed there don't help in solving the problem, please edit the steps you've tried and how they failed into the question and have it reopened.

Comment: It's not a duplicate. Each of those questions are different, or out-dated. This question is detailed and describes a specific situation that can't be solved with those ones marked as duplicate. Can you please re-open?

Comment: @patrix: None of your linked threads solves my question. The first one suggests obtaining Lion through the app store. However it has been removed from the app store AFAIK. The second and third link don't even mention Lion (Only Mountain Lion). Please remove the duplicate tag. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that, I didn't consider the "not available in Store" part.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have them in your Purchases in the Mac App store, you can order Lion and Mountain Lion directly from Apple for USD $19.99 each.

http://store.apple.com/us/product/D6106Z/A/os-x-lion
http://store.apple.com/us/product/D6377Z/A/os-x-mountain-lion